# Algorithm for Knapsack with repetition

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, pseudocode, knapsack-problem

I am trying to devise a pseudo-code for Knapsack algorithms, where a single item can be selected multiple times. The classical algorithm is

```
OPT(i, w) = max(OPT(i-1, w) or vi + OPT(i-1, w-wi))
```

In order to meet the requirements, I am modifying it to

```
k=1;
max = maximum(OPT(i-1, w))
while(OPT(i-1, w - k*wi) > 0) {
  maximum = max(maximum, k*vi + OPT(i-1, w - k*wi))
  k++
}
OPT(i, w) = maximum
```

Does this seem to be an appropriate solution? Or any better solution exists?
Please let me know if any additional information is required.
Rest all remains the same, vi denotes the value of ith element and wi denotes the weight of ith element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to be able to chose multiple items, all you have to do is to change the recursion when selecting an element:

```
OPT(i, w) = max(OPT(i-1, w) or vi + OPT(i, w-wi))
                     ^                   ^
          removed the element      not removing the element
```

The idea is, you allow readding it on next iteration. You add an element as much as you want, and you stop adding it when you "chose" to use the first condition in the stop recursive formula.

The recursion will still not be infinite because you must stop once `w<0`.

Time complexity does not change - `O(nW)`

Comment: By any chance, can we reduce this to a problem with 1D output?

Comment: I am not following what do you mean by "1D output". the output of `OPT` is a boolean value/

Comment: Since we are using i and W as variables, the space complexity of the code is O(nW). Can we somehow reduce it to O(n)?

Comment: @LearningToCode Space complexity can be O(W), because at each point you need the current column and the previous one - never more than that, so it can be done in O(W) space, with O(nW) time.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Algorithms DVP, the solution to Knapsack with repetition is like below:

```
K(0)=0
for w=1 to W:
    K(w) = max{K(w - w_i) + v_i, w_i < w}
return K(W)
```

Here, W is the capacity; w_i is the weight of item i; v_i is the value of item i; K(w) is the max value achievable with knapsack of capacity w.

Your solution seems like 0-1 Knapsack though.